# Redirecionar Requisição AJAX Cross-Domain no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, redirecionamento

Tenho um código que redireciona uma requisição AJAX e ela funciona normalmente em *localhost*, porém no servidor de hospedagem *cross-browser* a requisição não é redirecionado.

```
header('Location: http://dominio.com/endereco');
exit;
```

Bloquear redirecionamento de requisições AJAX é algo padrão?

Existe algum código pra habilitar tal redirecionamento?

Pode conter erro no meu código?

Eu faço a requisição utilizando jQuery.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://dominio.com/controller/action",
   data:dados,
   dataType: "json",
   success: Sucesso,
   error: Erro
})
```

Comment: São diferentes domínios, onde esta executando o ajax e o domínio do redirecionamento?

Comment: porque vc não usa JS pra redireciona, `location.href ='http://dominio.com/endereco' `

Comment: Faça o PHP retornar por JSON ou o valor da URL apenas para que seja redicionado o link do lado do cliente

Comment: São sub-domínios diferentes, exemplo: `http://api.dominio.com` e `http://teste.api.dominio.com`

Comment: Não posso fazer o redirecionamento via Javascript, porquê estou construindo uma API, e esse redirecionamento faz parte da regra da API e não do consumidor dela.

Comment: Que eu saiba, os navegadores bloqueiam requisições AJAX pra fora do site que está fazendo a requisição. Isso é por segurança e talvez tenha alguma exceção caso a URL seja localhost. Tenta confirmar se não é esse o problema, e ver o código retornado pela função no inspecionar.

Comment: Provavelmente é isso, conversei com um professor da faculdade e ele comentou que isso pode ser uma configuração padrão dos browsers, onde uma requisição _cross-domain_ não pode ser redirecionada por motivos de segurança.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa habilitar no seu servidor que será acessado por um domínio externo a permissão para que o domínio externo o acesse. Considerando `http://api.dominio.com` como seu domínio principal, e `http://teste.api.dominio.com` como seu domínio "externo", no `index.php` de `http://api.dominio.com` você vai ter:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://teste.api.dominio.com");
```

permitindo assim que `http://teste.api.dominio.com` execute seu *request Ajax*.

Seu servidor principal (`http://api.dominio.com`) precisa também retornar dados em formato [JSONP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), que é a extensão do formato JSON para permitir o *Cross-domain request*. E no seu *script Ajax* utilize `JSONP` como a extensão esperada:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://dominio.com/controller/action",
   data:dados,
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: Sucesso,
   error: Erro
});
```

Comment: O `Allow-Origin` já está presente no ´codigo, por que o redirecionamento funcionaria com `jsonp` e não com `json`?

Comment: @kaduamaral talvez eu tenha entendido errado sua pergunta. Entedi que você está tentando pegar dados de um servidor `A` invocando `$.ajax()`  em um servidor `B`.

Comment: Em teoria é isso, e estou conseguindo. O problema é quando tento redirecionar a requisição, como por exemplo quando a autenticação do usuário falha. Pelo que testei e pesquisei acho que isso não é possível, parece que o próprio browser interrompe a requisição quando recebe o cabeçalho de redirecionamento... :/